# React.js: Axois Post stay on pending(but i am getting data)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am using axios to perform post request to Node.js. The data does arrive the backend and I can perform some action with it. However, in the network, it always stay pending.

Example routers are following:

```
  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var added = this.getAddedItems()

    console.log("added is", added)
    if(added.length > 0){
      for(let i of added){
        console.log(i)
      }

      axios({ method: 'post', url: '/add', data: added})
    }
  }

handleDelete(e,desc){
        e.preventDefault()
        axios({method: "post", url: "/remove", data:{name: desc}})

    var newTotal = 0;

    var newArray = this.state.testData.filter(function(obj){
        return obj.desc !== desc
    })

    newArray.map(item => (
        newTotal += item.total
    ))

    console.log(newTotal)
    this.setState({ 
        testData: newArray,
        total: newTotal
    })
}

   handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        var remain = this.state.wallet - this.state.total

        this.setState({
            buyAttempt: true,
        })

        console.log("remain is " + remain)
        console.log("length " + this.state.testData.length)
        if(remain >= 0 && this.state.testData.length > 0){
            this.setState({buySuccessful: true})
            axios({ method: 'post', url: '/buy', data: { amount : remain}})



            this.setState({
                wallet:remain,
                testData: [],
                //itemNum:0
            })
        }
    }
```

These are the methods from my component. They all perform post request. The backend is actually receiving the data so I did not notice it. However, recently my app broke and I am suspecting that it is because of the never-ending pending.

I am also getting error message that will literally break my app

```
POST http://localhost:3000/add net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)

POST http://localhost:3000/buynet::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)

POST http://localhost:3000/remove net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
```

**What I need help with:**
1: How to fix this problem
2: Is there a better alternative way(react's natural way of performing post request)

My server.js

```
app.post('/buy', (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    var dbo = db.db("wallet");
    var myquery = { amount: {$gt: 0} }
    var newquery = { $set: {amount: req.body.amount}}
    dbo.collection("account").updateOne(myquery, newquery, function(err, re) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log("Wallet updated:", req.body.amount )
      db.close();
    });
  });


  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err, db) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    var dbo = db.db("cart");
    dbo.collection("items").deleteMany({}, function(err, res){
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log("numer of data deleted " + res.deletedCount)
      db.close();
    });
  });


});

app.post('/remove', (req,res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err,db){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    var dbo = db.db("cart");
    var myquery = { desc: req.body.name}
    console.log(req.body.name)
    dbo.collection("items").deleteMany(myquery, function(err,res){
      if(err) console.log(err);
      console.log("Numer of record deleted " + res.deletedCount)
      db.close();
    })
  })
})

app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("cart");
    var objs = req.body;
    dbo.collection("items").insertMany(objs, function(err, result) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log("Number of documents inserted: " + result.insertedCount);
      db.close()
    });
  });
});
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.6",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5",
    "reactstrap": "^6.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001"
}
```

Comment: Is your backend api's successfully inserts data into db?

Comment: Does your backend reponse something for that post request? Add your backed handler code..

Comment: @Think-Twice yes. However, I will sometimes receive error message like this, please see my update

Comment: @Hardy yeah, I can print them out by doing `req.body`, so I am catually getting the data, but it is just that they are always pending and now my app runs into an issue and I am suspecting that they are the reason for it, so I need to find a fix

Comment: Can you try in other browser and see if it works?

Comment: I think this problem is in your backend.. you should return code 200 etc from backend after handling the data.. also catch errors in your backend correctly..

Comment: @Hardy how would I do that, I posted my backend, please take a look

Comment: @Think-Twice I am trying to see if IE produces same error, please give me 2 minutes

Comment: In your backend.. send response something like `res.send(200, {status:'ok'});`

Comment: @Think-Twice yeah IE has the same problem(not as frequent as chrome from my experience at this point). The button will literally not work for Firefox

Comment: Read this: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are not sending resposne back in api call. You need to send response in every api call like I mentioned below

```
app.post('/buy', (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    var dbo = db.db("wallet");
    var myquery = { amount: {$gt: 0} }
    var newquery = { $set: {amount: req.body.amount}}
    dbo.collection("account").updateOne(myquery, newquery, function(err, result) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      res.send("Wallet updated);
      //if you want to send in json format then
      res.json({"message": "Wallet updated", "result": result});
      console.log("Wallet updated:", req.body.amount )
      db.close();
    });
  });


  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err, db) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    var dbo = db.db("cart");
    dbo.collection("items").deleteMany({}, function(err, result){
      if (err) console.log(err);
      res.send("numer of data deleted " + result.deletedCount)
      db.close();
    });
  });


});

app.post('/remove', (req,res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err,db){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    var dbo = db.db("cart");
    var myquery = { desc: req.body.name}
    console.log(req.body.name)
    dbo.collection("items").deleteMany(myquery, function(err,result){
      if(err) console.log(err);
      res.send("Numer of record deleted " + result.deletedCount)
      db.close();
    })
  })
})

app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("cart");
    var objs = req.body;
    dbo.collection("items").insertMany(objs, function(err, result) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      res.send("Number of documents inserted: " + result.insertedCount);
      db.close()
    });
  });
});
```

Also in every api call you have res twice so change one res to result or any name on your choice. because node will get confused about two res. So I have changed res to result in every api call.

Comment: This fixed the pending issue . However, now it is breaking my get route because it says  `Proxy error: Could not proxy request /total from localhstem_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).ost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/.`