# React + Express: Proxy error: Could not proxy request /total from localhstem_errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

This is a follow-up question from my previous question
[React.js: Axois Post stay on pending(but i am getting data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652872/react-js-axois-post-stay-on-pendingbut-i-am-getting-data/52653098?noredirect=1#comment92238260_52653098)

My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.6",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5",
    "reactstrap": "^6.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001"
}
```

My server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());


//DB connections
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

// console.log that your server is up and running
app.listen(3001, () => console.log(`Listening on port 3001`));


// create a GET route
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  var data;
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("mydb");
    var query = { address: "Highway 37" };
    dbo.collection("customers").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      data = result
      res.send(data[0])
      db.close();
    });
  });
});

//A Get route for getting personal Cart information
app.get('/myCart', (req, res) => {
  var total = 0;
  var data = []

  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("cart");
    dbo.collection("items").find().toArray(function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;

      var obj = []
      if(result.length >0){
        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++ ){
          var description = result[i].desc;
          var price = result[i].price
          if (!obj[description]) { // Add new object to result
            obj[description] = {
                desc: description,
                total: price,
                amount: 1
            };
          }else{
            obj[description].total += price
            obj[description].amount +=1
          }
        }

        for(var key in obj){
          console.log(obj[key])
          data.push(obj[key])
          total += obj[key].total
        }
      }

      res.send({express: data})
      db.close();
    });
  });



}); 


//a Post route for posting the added item to the data base
app.post('/add', (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("cart");
    var objs = req.body;
    dbo.collection("items").insertMany(objs, function(err, result) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      res.sendStatus(200)
      console.log("Number of documents inserted: " + result.insertedCount);
      db.close()
    });
  });
});


app.get('/wallet', (req, res) => {
  var data;
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("wallet");
    dbo.collection("account").findOne({}, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.send( {express: result.amount})
      db.close();
    });
  });


});

app.get('/total', (req, res) => {
  var total = 0;

  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("cart");
    dbo.collection("items").find().toArray(function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      for(let item of result){
        total += item.price;
      }
      res.send({express: total})
      db.close();
    });
  });
});

app.post('/buy', (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    var dbo = db.db("wallet");
    var myquery = { amount: {$gt: 0} }
    var newquery = { $set: {amount: req.body.amount}}
    dbo.collection("account").updateOne(myquery, newquery, function(err, re) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      res.sendStatus(200)
      console.log("Wallet updated:", req.body.amount )
      db.close();
    });
  });


  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err, db) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    var dbo = db.db("cart");
    dbo.collection("items").deleteMany({}, function(err, res){
      if (err) console.log(err);
      res.sendStatus(200)
      console.log("numer of data deleted " + res.deletedCount)
      db.close();
    });
  });

});

app.post('/remove', (req,res) => {
  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err,db){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    var dbo = db.db("cart");
    var myquery = { desc: req.body.name}
    console.log(req.body.name)
    dbo.collection("items").deleteMany(myquery, function(err,res){
      if(err) console.log(err);
      res.sendStatus(200)
      console.log("Numer of record deleted " + res.deletedCount)
      db.close();
    })
  })
})
```

The problem is that after adding res.send() to my code, now my route are all broken because of the Proxy error: Could not proxy request /total from localhstem_errors. This problem happened before. Actually it has been a warning since I created my react+express app, but it was just a warning and does not seem to affect my app, but now it does. Also, it is the `res.send()` in the post route that is causing the problem. In these get routers, `res.send()` was fine

Any fix to this? I feel like it is not going to be a trivial fix. May I have to restart my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try setting your proxy in package.json like

```
"proxy": {
    "/*":  {
        "target": "http://localhost:3001"
    }
}
```

Regarding below error the `res.sendStatus` should be placed out of mongo connection

> Can't set headers after they are sent

```
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) { 
   if (err) throw err; 
   var dbo = db.db("cart"); 
   var objs = req.body; 
   dbo.collection("items").insertMany(objs, function(err, result) { 
   if (err) console.log(err); 
   console.log("Number of documents inserted: " + result.insertedCount); 
   db.close() 
   }); 
}); 
   res.sendStatus(200) 
});
```

Comment: Getting rid of proxy or adding what you have both failed. As the add route response with `Cannot POST /add`

Comment: @aDev No holdon. What is the basepath of your backend service? You need replace your base path api name in place of basePath in my answer. I thought you will replace that with your backend service basepath. base path means you must be setting it in index.js file like app.use("/somepath", routes); like this

Comment: Let me post my server.js. I dont think I have a basepath, since the path it is all route

Comment: @aDev I got it. take my updated solution and give a try now

Comment: same thing. I am also getting the error from console that says:`"Can't set headers after they are sent."`

Comment: @aDev can you try adding the change from my updated answer

Comment: Same, apparently any method regarding res can't be used in this case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181307/discussion-between-think-twice-and-adev).