# React/Express App - API Requests to Backend Proxy error: Could not proxy request (ECONNRESET)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

**The problem:**

I'm working on a React app w/ a Node Express Server and MongoDB. When trying to make a post or get request from the client-side, we receive a 500 status code and the following error:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/workdays/allworkdays/5e5ee6a690f9a13de897d6a6 from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/.
[1] See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).
```

In the case of the post request, the information is posted to the database though, eventually, we do receive the same error message along w/ a 500 status code.

In the case of the get request, the request is consoled in the back-end terminal but is never received by the browser. The network tab reflects a (pending) designation, like so:

[Screenshot of network tab from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzP4W.png)

The intention of the get request is to query our Users collection - retrieve all linked workday ids, and then query the Workdays collection and retrieve all the documents w/ those ids.

The error message provides a link to an explanation of the error (ECONNRESET):

```
ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer): A connection was forcibly closed by a peer. This normally results from a loss of the connection on the remote socket due to a timeout or reboot. Commonly encountered via the http and net modules.
```

We hope to take this response and push it to the state as events.

The workflow of our app is Component -> Axios Call -> API Routes -> Controller -> DB

Any help regarding this error would be especially appreciated as I'm a student looking to be employed soon. I'm doing this project, in addition to learning, for the purpose of including it in my portfolio.

Thanks

**The error I'm getting:**

[Screenshot of console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNuty.png)

**Things I've tried:**

[React + Express: Proxy error: Could not proxy request /total from localhstem_errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653534/react-express-proxy-error-could-not-proxy-request-total-from-localhstem-err)

**The code:**

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mern",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev",
    "start:prod": "node server.js",
    "start:dev": "concurrently \"nodemon --ignore 'client/*'\" \"npm run client\"",
    "client": "cd client && npm run start",
    "seed": "node scripts/seedDB.js",
    "install": "cd client && npm install",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.1.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "if-env": "^1.0.4",
    "is-empty": "^1.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.24.0",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.7",
    "validator": "^12.2.0"
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from "react-big-calendar";
import "react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css";
import Modal from "../Modal";

import workdaysAPI from "../../utils/workdaysAPI";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

import "./calendar.css";

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

class MyCalendar extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    workdaysAPI
      .getAllThisEmployeeWorkdays(this.props.auth.user.id)
      .then(dbModel => 
        this.setState({
          events: dbModel
        })
      )
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  constructor() {
    super();

    const events = [];, etc.
```

**Axios Call**

```
**import axios from "axios";

export default {
  // Gets all workdays w/ user id
  getAllThisEmployeeWorkdays: function(id) {
    return axios.get("/api/workdays/allworkdays/" + id);
  }
};**
```

**API Routes**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const workdaysController = require("../../controllers/workdaysController");

const Workday = require("../../models/Workday");

// Matches with "/api/workdays"
router
  .get("/allworkdays/:id", (req, res) => {
    workdaysController.findAllById
});
```

**Controller**

```
const db = require("../models");

// Defining methods for the workdaysController

module.exports = {
  findAllById: function(req, res) {
    db.User
      .findById({ _id: req.params.id })
      .populate("workday")
      .then(err, workday => {
        db.Workday
          .findById({ workday })
          console.log("Returning all workdays ", workday.workday);
          res.json(workday.workday) 
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  }, etc.
```

**The Models**

Users

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  workday: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'workdays'
  }],
  schedule: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'schedules'
  }]
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

Workdays

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
// Create Schema
const WorkdaySchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  availability: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  },
  start: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  end: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  allDay: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  }
});

module.exports = Workday = mongoose.model("workdays", WorkdaySchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after reviewing the code 12986 times, I found an error in the syntax for the controller file below:

```
module.exports = {
  findAllById: function(req, res) {
    db.User
      .findById({ _id: req.params.id })
      .populate("workday")
      .then(err, workday => {
        db.Workday
          .findById({ workday })
          console.log("Returning all workdays ", workday.workday);
          res.json(workday.workday) 
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  }
```

After you query the database for the User by id (and populated the "workday" field), the .then is not grabbing the document and then sending a json response (i.e. `res.json(document)`).

I would suggest changing your code as follows:

```
findAllById: function(req, res) {
    db.User
      .findById(req.params.id)
      .populate("workday")
      .then(document => {
        res.json(document)
      console.log("Returning all workdays", document);
        return db.User.find(
          { workday: document }, 
        );
    })
  }
```

Hope this helps!